# Is it possible check whether a list of documentIds is present in given Index and Type in Elastic Search?

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I have a scenario in Elastic Search. I have a list of documentIds which I have to check whether all documentId's are present in a particular index and type(which will be provided). I need to know is that possible in Elastic Search querying methodology. If so , can you plz explain with an example ?

Additionally, supposing a documentId which is not present in the index is given, is it possible to retrieve that documentId ?

I have heard about script and scriptParams but I am unaware of it. Is it possible using that?
Plz explain with an example or provide a suitable link.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this would be to just try to retrieve all of the documents, using the [multi-get](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-multi-get.html) API:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/_mget" -d'
{ "ids": ["good_id", "missing_id"]}'
```

This will return an array of all docs. If any doc was not found, then `exists` will be set to `false` for that element.  (In v1.0, `exists` has been renamed to `found`).

If you don't want to retrieve the body of the document, then set the `fields` parameter to nothing in the query string:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/_mget?fields=" -d'
{ "ids": ["good_id", "missing_id"]}'
```

Comment: is there any java API to do this ?

Comment: Yes, the MultiGetRequestBuilder.  Anything you can do with the REST API you can also do with the Java API, and vice versa